# bootstrap-angular modal dialog: can not return value from select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular-bootstrap modal dialog with the following template (jade syntax):

```
div.modal-body
  select(ng-model="chosenProject" id="chosenProject",  ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in selectItems")
div.modal-footer
  button.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="ok()")   Change project
  button.btn.btn-warning(ng-click="cancel()")  Cancel
```

The pre-filling of the array works just fine. Dialog is configured with its controller that defines trivial ok() function, below is the excepmt from controller's body:

```
        $scope.chosenProject = 0;  // needed to have selected initial item with value=-1 in the select
        $scope.ok = function () {
            console.log("OK clicked, chosenProject " + $scope.chosenProject);
            $modalInstance.close($scope.chosenProject);
        };
```

The functions work fine. Accodring to console.log, $scope.chosenProject remains the same regardiless of what I chose in select and simply returns whatever I preset in line "$scope.chosenProject = 0;". I appreciate an advice how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because of a transclusion scope that exists between your controller and the modal template.

Try this instead - In the controller for the modal, replace:

```
$scope.chosenProject = 0;
```

with

```
$scope.chosenProject = {
    value: 0
};
```

And the modal template, replace

```
select(ng-model="chosenProject" id="chosenProject"  
       ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in selectItems")
```

with

```
select(ng-model="chosenProject.value" id="chosenProject" 
       ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in selectItems")
```

The selected project should then be captured properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass chosenProject back in

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(result) {
});
```

[This](http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/AmBpL) is a very good simpler dialog service to use if you need a couple more dialog in one page.